# Report job status/progress in close() method

Tags: hadoop, distributed-computing

I hit the timeout issue in hadoop and my job gets killed. There is a heavy clean up work in close() method, so I'll need to update the progress in close method when doing those clean up.

Increasing timeout is not a good option for this case because it is not scalable with the amount of clean up work.

The legacy job that I'm looking at is using the old API, it has a reporter object in reduce() method that can be used to update the progress. However, there is no such Reporter in close() method. So is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Mapper.Context](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.Context.html).

Hadoop provides the Prograssable  interface which contains this interesting method `Public void Progress()`. The Context class implements this interface, so any mapper or reducer can call:

```
context.progress()
```

to show it is alive and continues to process.

---

As a last resort, since you are convinced it's not a good option, you could increase that configuration property:

```
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.task.timeout</name>
  <value>2000000</value>
</property>
```

in "mapred-site.xml".

Or do this in your code:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
long milliSeconds = 2000 * 60 * 60;
conf.setLong("mapreduce.task.timeout", milliSeconds);
```

The higher this property's value, the better, for your case. The default value is 600000.

Comment: A similar class in old API is called Reporter. But it is not passed into close() method in reducer. Is the reporter a singleton for a reducer during its life time? If yes, can I assign it to a object level field and use it later for reporting progress?